# Count occurrences of inf in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

We can count occurrences of `nan` with `df.isna().count()`
Is there is a similar function to count `inf`?

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/q/28102302/6692898 . If it does please flag this question as duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [`np.isinf()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isinf.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'data' : [0,0,float('inf'),float('inf')]})


print(df)

   data
0   0.0
1   0.0
2   inf
3   inf


df.groupby(np.isinf(df['data'])).count()

       data
data       
False     2
True      2
```

Comment: We have to count for every column and not entire dataframe?

Comment: @Naveed sorry you mean you want to count all `inf` values across the entire dataframe? maybe - `np.isinf(df.stack()).groupby(level=1).sum()`

Comment: Its throwing the following error:
`TypeError: ufunc 'isinf' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`

Comment: May be because I have a `datetime.date` column (other 2 columns are string and float)

Comment: yes `inf` can only appear in a `float` column, maybe try `df.select_dtypes('float')` first then use the groupby

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me:

```
number_inf = df[df == np.inf].count()
```

Comment: one needs to make sure to count -np.inf (negative infinity)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `isinf()` and `ravel()` in one line

```
# Pandas Series.ravel() function returns the flattened underlying data as an ndarray.
np.isinf(df["Col"]).values.ravel().sum()
```